# FBGraph message containing embedded link text in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fb-graph

I am new in FBGraph and ruby.
I am using FBGraph api for facebook and the following code for posting.
`me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
me.feed!(
  :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
)`

Its working fine for me.

I want to post a message containing an html tag `<a href= "somelink">Text</a>`

Please advice.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the following to me.feed! (I added some others just for good measure):

```
        me.feed!(
        :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
        :name => 'Update',
        :link => 'http://www.somelink.com/',
        :description => 'My description'
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I need a message Like this "Updating via FbGraph <here a text which is a link pointing to a URL>"  For example "Hello world [link](http://google.com) "